# Did Boeing build airliners other than the 7x7 series?

Tags: airliner, boeing, aircraft-identification

What I mean by the 7x7 series is the 707, 717, 727, etc. I took this picture at the Pima Air and Space Museum in Tucson, Arizona.

[image: Aircraft at Pima Air and Space Museum]

What type of aircraft is this? Was it an airliner? I know that no 7x7 series aircraft was that small, so were there other airliners made by Boeing besides the 7x7 series?

[image: Closeup of previous aircraft at Pima Air and Space Museum]

Comment: The aircraft looks a lot like a miniature Boeing 787. Has similar aerodynamic design.

Comment: I had to take pictures of this aircraft at the museum, I found it extremely interesting, so I am wondering what it is called, so I could do some research about it.

Comment: So, it looks like we already had plans to design the 787 back in the 1950s :)

Comment: @RaajTram The shape of it really looks like a mini 787 and the funny thing is that the museum has a 787 to view also. So 2 787's.

Comment: @Ethan: `I know that no 7x7 series aircraft was that small`... the Caravelle (the aircraft pictured) is in fact _larger_ (31m long, 34m span) than the original Boeing 737 (29m long, 28m span). Be careful with absolute statements like that! :)

Comment: See Also: [this Boeing Frontiers article on Boeing's model numbering scheme](http://www.boeing.com/news/frontiers/archive/2004/february/i_history.html)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

**Yes, Boeing built other airliners, with different numbering**, although none of them were jet-powered. Three iconic designs come to my mind right away, although there were others:

The [Boeing 247](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boeing_247) predated the DC-3 into service, and was a highly advanced twin-engine, monoplane cabin design. It was a pioneering aircraft, introducing all-metal construction, a cantilever wing, and retractable landing gear. It was later surpassed by the DC-3, as the 247's cabin was too small for serious airline service.
[image]

The [Boeing 314 "Clipper"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boeing_314_Clipper) was a large four-engine flying-boat transport from just before World War II. Not quite as pioneering as the 247D, it nonetheless was massive for its time and heavily influenced later large Boeing designs.
[image]

The [Boeing 377 "Stratocruiser"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boeing_377_Stratocruiser) was a post-World War II design based on the B-29 bomber, with a double-deck (double-bubble) fuselage and four piston engines. It was large, pressurized, and technologically advanced, but relatively unsuccessful in sales compared to contemporary designs like the Lockheed Constellation.
[image]

As others have mentioned, the aircraft in your question is a [Sud Caravelle](http://www.airvectors.net/avcomet.html#m4), which was designed to solve the same problem as the later Boeing 737: it was a shorter-range airliner meant for smaller routes. You point out how much the Caravelle's nose looks like the Boeing 787, and you're right - but it is even more similar to the [De Havilland Comet](http://www.airvectors.net/avcomet.html); Sud licensed the design from De Havilland.

<sub>*All photos from Wikipedia.*</sub>

Answer (score 10):

To start with that picture from Pima Air and Space Museum:

It is a **Sud SE-210 Caravelle VI-R** - the world's first medium-range jet airliner (source: Wikipedia). This particular airplane has nothing to do with Boeing. I believe it's in the Museum due to the fact that it was the world's first medium-range airliner.

[image]

You can read all about it at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sud_Aviation_Caravelle.

To answer your question about whether or not Boeing had anything apart from the 700-series: it does. Not to forget the purchase of MD.

A list of ALL airplanes under Boeing can be found at: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category:Boeing_aircraft.

Comment: I have to ask.. what is that thing hanging down from the underside, just behind the front wheel? spare gas tank? a bomb?

Comment: @user2813274 I'm wondering the same. First thought was that it is some sort of a marker beacon antenna, or maybe a glideslope or localizer receiver O.o

Comment: This a/c was first flown by United Airlines, and was purchased by Aero Service (as [N1001U](https://www.flickr.com/photos/23032926@N05/4929458537)) which used it as a radar testbed. Hence the pod. More at [Airliners.net](http://www.airliners.net/search/photo.search?regsearch=N1001U&distinct_entry=true).

Comment: When Boeing purchased MacDonell-Douglas, the only civilian type still in production, MD-90, was renamed to 717, so in _that_ event Boeing was not making any airliners not in the 7x7 series. Boeing did produce many airliner with other numbers _before_ the 7x7 series though.

Comment: @JanHudec: Actually, McDonnell Douglas had _two_ civilian aircraft in production when they merged with Boeing in 1997: the DC-9 (in its DC-9-80 [MD-80] and DC-9-93 [MD-90] variants) and the MD-11.  The DC-9-80 and DC-9-93 remained in production until 1999 and 2000, respectively, and a third DC-9 variant, the DC-9-95 (MD-95; Boeing 717) entered production in 1999, where it remained until 2006; the passenger version of the MD-11 was discontinued as soon as the airframes under construction at the time of the merger were completed, but Boeing continued to produce cargo MD-11s until 2000.

Answer (score 5):

There was also Boeing 720, a shorter, smaller version of the Boeing 707. Wikipedia article here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boeing_720

Answer (score 4):

All the Boeing civil *jet* aircraft (which are the only ones under production/operation) are named in the 7x7 series. The military aircraft follow the US DoD designations, like C-17 Globemaster III, K-46 Pegasus (which is a modified 767) etc.

The aircraft is a [Sud Aviation SE 210 Caravelle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sud_Aviation_Caravelle), produced by the French firm Sud Aviation.

[image: Sud Caravelle]

"[Finnair Caravelle Basle Airport - April 1976](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Finnair_Caravelle_Basle_Airport_-_April_1976.jpg#/media/File:Finnair_Caravelle_Basle_Airport_-_April_1976.jpg)" by Eduard Marmet - http://www.airliners.net/open.file/0101623/L/Transferred from en.wikipedia. Licensed under CC BY-SA 3.0 via [Commons](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/).

It was the first short/medium-range jet airliner. It first flew in 1955 and was operated till 2004, with around 282 numbers built.

Comment: The cockpit windows are different comparing my picture to your is this a different variant.

Comment: @Ethan Appears that the cockpit windows have been painted over.